# If I was mapping thru a collection, and placing buttons for each doc, how could I grab the docID from the button to its function?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, jsx

How could one grab the documentID of the Button from a mapped dataset, where each item is an object?

```
function doSomethingWithDocID = () => {
    firestore.collection("MainESGfeed")
    .doc(documentID)
    .update({likes: increment })

    console.log("liked!")
}

return(
{data.map((itemObject, pos) => { 
  const {likes, comments, documentID} = itemObject
<div> 
  {likes}
  {comments}
  
    <Button onClick={doSomethingWithDocID}/> 
</div>  
  )
 } 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an arrow function, and supply `documentID` when you call `doSomethingWithDocID`:

```
return data.map((documentID, pos) => (
  <div>   
      <Button key={documentID} onClick={() => doSomethingWithDocID(documentID)}/> 
  </div>  
)
```

Comment: It appears documentID is not actually the documentID, it is the whole data object.